# jdbc driver class not found error

Tags: java

I'm getting this error while trying to load the jdbc driver, here's my code:

```
    Class.forName("com.jdbc.mysql.driver").newInstance();
```

I've checked the class path, and build path (using eclipse), it's fine. Anyone knows what might be the problem?

Comment: Note that you don't need to create an instance with `newInstance()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh um, it's suppose to be

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

not `jdbc.mysql.driver`

It should work now.